# Switching Between More than Two Shared Libraries (LD_PRELOAD)

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, symbols, ld-preload

Suppose that there exists three shared libraries `A.so`, `B.so` and `C.so`, each having a function `f()`. I want to switch between each function `f()` under certain circumstances, determined at runtime. Using the `LD_PRELOAD` trick, I will execute the program `p` (i.e., the user of these libraries) as follows:

```
LD_PRELOAD=A.so:B.so:C.so ./p
```

`f()` in `A.so` will be the default. In that `f()` instance, I can access `f()` of `B.so` using `dlsym()`, as follows:

```
void f() // in A.so
{
...
    void *f_in_B = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "f");
...
}
```

How can I access the `f()` instance in `C.so`?

---

**UPDATE:**

Although [`yugr`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64309181/6661026) works in the **simple** case, it has **problems** in more **general** conditions. I will shed some light on the problem by giving more **details** the **current** situation:

I need two **different** dynamic memory **allocators** and do **not** want to deal with **internal** implementation details of `glibc` `malloc(),...`. Put simply, I have two **separate** memory areas each with its own `glibc`. I use `LD_PRELOAD` to **switch** between the allocators based on some **runtime** condition. I used [`yugr`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64309181/6661026) to load and access the **secondary** library.

Firstly, I called `ptmalloc_init()` in the secondary library to **initialize** `malloc()` data structures. I have also **managed** `brk()` calls at the OS system call level in such a way that **each** library has its **own** large `brk()` range and this **avoids** further conflicts.

The problem is that the solution works **only** at the `application/glibc` boundary. For example, when I use `malloc()` in the **secondary** library, it calls functions such as `__default_morecore()` in the **primary** library, **internally**, and these calls can **not** be captured by the `LD_PRELOAD` trick.

**Why** does this happen? I thought that the internal symbols of a library are set **internally** at the library **compilation time**, but, **here**, it seems that they **use** the symbols in the **primary** library of `LD_PRELOAD`. If the resolution is done by the **linker**, why these seemingly internal symbols are **not** captured by the `LD_PRELOAD` trick?

How can I **fix** the problem? Should I **rename** all the **exported** functions in the **secondary** library? Or the **only** feasible approach is to use a **single** library and **delve into** the implementation stuff?

Comment: Read documentation of [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and of [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html), and provide some [mre] in your question. Read also Drepper's paper [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) and the documentation of [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils), [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)

Comment: Is this some kind of challenge or an actual problem?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond, this is an actual one. I have to use **modified** implementations of **some functions** in `glibc` and use them **instead of** the original ones, under **certain** conditions. You can assume that `A.so` is my wrapper which **checks** the condition and **selects** between the **original** function in `glibc` (e.g., `B.so`) and the **customized** one (e.g., `C.so`).

Comment: Or should I do checks at the beginning of `f()` in the customized `glibc` and use it as the default one? Indeed, this will solve the problem but will not work for more than two instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `dlopen` each of the three libraries at startup to obtain their handles and use those to call `dlsym(h, "f")` to get particular implementations of `f`. If you don't know library names in advance you could use `dl_iterate_phdr` to obtain them (see [this code](https://github.com/jethrogb/ssltrace/blob/bf17c150a7/ssltrace.cpp#L74-L112) for example).